# Javascript submit not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This seems like a really simple question but, for whatever reason my `submit()` method is not being invoked in JS.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-view title="Register" hide-nav-bar="true" nav-transition="none" id="page9">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding" scroll="false">
        <form id="register-form4" ng-submit="register()" class="list">
            <ion-list id="register-list4">
                <label class="item item-input" id="register-input7">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="registration.email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input" id="register-input9">
                    <input type="password" ng-model="registration.password" placeholder="Password" required>
                </label>
            </ion-list>
        </form>
        <a id="register-button7" ng-click="document.getElementById('register-form4').submit();" class="button button-positive  button-block">Create Account</a>
        <a ui-sref="login" id="register-button8" class="button button-positive  button-block button-clear">Back</a>
        <div ng-show="isError">{{ loginError }}</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller:**

```
.controller('registerCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', "$firebaseAuth", "$location",
function ($scope, $stateParams, $firebaseAuth, $location) {
    $scope.register = function() {
    var email = $scope.registration.email,
        password = $scope.registration.password,
        confirmPassword = $scope.registration.confirmPassword;

        console.log("Being submitted");
    }
}])
```

I cannot change the `<a>` tag even though it would be easier just to have a form submit `input` but the HTML is auto-generated by Ionic Creator and I can't mess it up.

**EDIT:** The reason I want to submit the form in this way and not just trigger `register()` on click of the button is that I want to trigger the HTML `required`'s in the form so that checks the fields have been entered so I don't have to do it manually

**EDIT 2:** I have changed the `<a>` tag to a submit button. However, this is still not invoking the `register()` method which suggests the form is not being submitted:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create Account" id="register-button7" class="button button-positive  button-block">
```

Looking at these [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit), it should work as it's pretty much the same format

I have read that 1 user things that the standard HTML `submit` and `ng-submit` do not work together. Anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Try using "onclick" instead of "ng-click".

Comment: Why don't you just set `ngClick` to `ng-click="register()"`?  I don't see any reason you have to find the form element to submit the form in this case.  The code above doesn't work because `$scope.document` is not defined.  Also, I would argue your current use of `document.getElementById()` is not "the Angular way." TM

Comment: @c1moore I did have that originally. The idea behind it is that if I submit the form, it will trigger the HTML `required`'s just so I don't have to check them manually

Comment: @wmash See my edits below.  Your best choice to do this "the Angular way" TM is to create a new directive.

Comment: @c1moore I've checked with the guy doing the UI and he says I can change it to a submit button. However, this is still not invoking the `register()` method. I will update my question

Comment: You should move the submit button into your form

Comment: @StefanNegele it is in my form...

Comment: @StefanNegele sorry, I see the confusion. Since the first lot of code. I have moved the button inside the form

Comment: Did it work? It should submit the form now.

Comment: @StefanNegele unfortunately not. I have tried standard onsubmit as well instead of ng-submit but no luck

Comment: There must be a syntax error or  similar. In this link is a working example: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-10-form-handling-and-validation/

Comment: @StefanNegele my syntax is correct. The differences between mine and the example you gave is that my submit is an input, not a button. I will try this when I dan

Comment: @wmash Where is registration defined or initialized?  That may be your problem

Comment: Using `<input>` or `<button>` won't make a difference (I have used both in my forms).

Comment: I have added a working demo for calling register method from the link's click event: `ng-click="register()"`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I will try this demo when I can. Will it trigger the HTML's required?

Comment: @c1moore I will update the question to show where the controllers are declared and initialised but it's basically done via a $scopeProvider. When a path is hit, sets the controller and template to use

Comment: Yes @wmash, now is working a demo as required: clicking in a link outside of the form and triggering the HTML's required

Comment: @YosvelQuintero that is not the proper way to go about this.  [This link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) lists things you should not use controllers for and the first item is DOM manipulation.  Using a directive as I did is a better solution.

Comment: Good comment @c1moore. Moved the DOM manipulation logic to a directive `submitForm`.. Check the working demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use html `input` of type submit or a `button` inside your form. Here is a working demo at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydbhb5dL/

Controller:

```
angular
    .module('App', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.registration = {};

        $scope.register = function () {
            var email = $scope.registration.email,
                password = $scope.registration.password;

            console.log('Email:', email);
            console.log('Password:', password);
            console.log('Being submitted!');
        };
    });
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ExampleController">
<ion-view title="Register" hide-nav-bar="true" nav-transition="none" id="page9">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding" scroll="false">
    <form id="register-form4" ng-submit="register()" class="list">
        <ion-list id="register-list4">
        <label class="item item-input" id="register-input7">
            <input type="text" ng-model="registration.email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="register-input9">
            <input type="password" ng-model="registration.password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </label>
        </ion-list>

        <input type="submit" class="button-like-link" value="Create Account (button)">
    </form>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</div>
```

Comment: I've attempted to run the snippet but does not seem to be working

Comment: Apologies for not replying. Yes I have and it works! Is there anyway to prompt the default HTML alerts when a field is required?

Answer (score -1):

To solve your problem change the `<a>` element that submits the form to

```
<a id="register-button7" ng-click="register()" class="button button-positive  button-block">Create Account</a>
```

The reason `ngClick` wasn't working before is because it was looking at `$scope` for `document`, which is not defined.  You *could* add the following line to your controller, but it's not necessary.

```
$scope.document = document;
```

If you insist on not changing the form structure, you can create a new directive for your submit "button" similar to the one below (untested).

```
angular.module('moduleName').directive('submitForm', function() {
    return {
         restrict:   'A',
         scope:      {
             formId:   '='
         },
         link:       function($scope, $elem) {
             $elem.on('click', function() {
                 document.getElementById($scope.formId).submit();
             });
         }
    };
});
```

Which you would then use as follows:

```
<a id="register-button7" submit-form form-id="register-form4" class="button button-positive button-block">Create Account</a>
```

If you still don't want to change the `<a>` tag to use the new directive, your only other option is defining `$scope.document = document`.

Or, as @J Orbe mentioned, you could use `onclick` instead of relying on an Angular directive (i.e. `ngClick` and `submitForm`).  I'm not sure this qualifies as the "Angular way" TM, though, and you may want to avoid mixing Angular and regular JavaScript attributes as it can result in confusion.  Typically, if you're using Angular, you should try to solve things using Angular.

Comment: Why did you downvote this answer?  This answered the OP's original question, provided good practice solutions, and explained why it didn't work.

Comment: You're using AngularJS anti pattern, thats not how you should solve and explain it.

Comment: @StefanNegele What anti-pattern exactly?  I've seen this suggested many other places.  You don't want to mix HTML logic in a controller as it makes for untestable code (therefore you shouldn't place `document` in `$scope` and try to search for an element).  Instead you should use a directive that separates that logic

Comment: It´s the `document.getElementById` what seems odd to me. But I also see your point with the HTML logic.